# solr TTL on documents using DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory in Cloud mode not working

Tags: solr, solrcloud, ttl

I am trying to implement TTL on solr documents as mentioned in below link:

[DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory.html)

The changes are working fine when I start solr in stand alone mode in my local machine. But when I start solr in cloud mode (example cloud mode available with Solr installation) and do the necessary changes (mentioned below) the expire_at field does not get updated with the calculated date value from my_ttl field.
I can see the saved document only has my_ttl field and id field the expires_at field is not available in the saved document.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong in this case?

**changes in solr-config.xml**

```
 <updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">
<!-- UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory will generate an id if none is present in the incoming document -->
<processor class="solr.processor.DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="ttlFieldName">my_ttl_</str>
    <str name="ttlParamName">_ttl_</str>
    <int name="autoDeletePeriodSeconds">120</int>
    <str name="expirationFieldName">expires_at_</str>
</processor>
<processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
<processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
```

**changes in managed-schema file**

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="my_ttl" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
<field name="expires_at_" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
```

**POST REQUEST**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '[{"id":"1","my_ttl":"+120SECONDS"}]' http://localhost:8983/solr/dailyforecasts/update?comit=true
```

{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":8}}

This update works successfully but the expires_at_ field is not updated in the saved document, so the document really never gets deleted inspite of the time set in sole-config.xml

But if I explicitly set the expires_at_ field in the document to a date in past then the document is saved and also gets deleted after the expiry trigger time.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '[{"id":"1","my_ttl":"+120SECONDS", "expires_at_":"2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"}]' http://localhost:8983/solr/dailyforecasts/update?comit=true
```

Comment: So where are you making these changes? Does it work if you use the field name `_ttl_` (the default)? When you're running in cloud mode, all configuration data is stored in zookeeper.

Comment: I could see the configuration changes displayed on solr UI from the files in the cloud option.
I am downloading the config from zookeeper and changing it and uploading it again. The config does not work with _ttl_ param as well.

Comment: @MatsLindh i am making the changes in managed-schema and solr-config.xml after downloading the config from zk, using the solr zk commands downconfig and upconfig to upload the config back.

Answer (score 0):

finally i figured out why the above changes were not working.
I have to mention the name of the update request processor chain in my request otherwise solr will use a default update request processor chain.
After i add the `update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema` as a parameter to the request URL the solr document after indexing had the expires_at_ field populated correctly as expected.

> localhost:8983/solr/coll1/update?commit=true&update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema